# SQLite JOIN WHERE not in multiple tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, medoo

Im using sqlite and have the following schema and table data

```
"CREATE TABLE numbers (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,   
    cli INTEGER UNIQUE
);"

"CREATE TABLE allocated (
    did_id INTEGER,
    cli INTEGER UNIQUE,
    client_id INTEGER
);"

"CREATE TABLE used (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    cli INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    client_id INTEGER,
    date DATETIME
);"
```

Example data

```
table `numbers`
id  cli
11  444
12  555
13  666
14  777
15  888
16  999

table `allocated`
did_id  cli
14  777
12  555

table `used`
id  cli
31  111
31  222
32  444
33  999
```

I want to get the column data "cli" from `numbers` table where "cli" in not in table `allocated` or table `used`.

expected result

```
numbers
id cli 
13 666
15 888
```

First off I like to know what is the sqlite query to for this will be.
If possible then I would like to apply it with Medoo php library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is a double anti-join:

```
SELECT n.id, n.cli
FROM numbers n
LEFT JOIN allocated a
    ON n.cli = a.cli
LEFT JOIN used u
    ON n.cli = u.cli
WHERE
    a.cli IS NULL AND u.cli IS NULL;
```

We could also use `EXISTS` here:

```
SELECT n.id, n.cli
FROM numbers n
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM allocated a WHERE a.cli = n.cli) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM used u WHERE u.cli = n.cli);
```